# not able to create individual and assign its property in python

Tags: python, owl, ontology

I have created ontology and store in owl file using protege. now i want to store RDF in ntriple file using previously created owl ontology. I have class city which have cityName as data property and cityInCountry as object property. I am trying to create individual of class City. it not allow to assign data property give error that property is not define. i try by removing data property it will successfully create and write in ntriples file. But it also import my full owl file also in ntriples file. can i keep separate both files?

```
from owlready2 import *
onto=get_ontology('path to ontology temp.owl')
onto.load()
print(list( onto.classes()))

base=get_namespace('to get IRI')

with onto:
    obj=base.City('abc')
    obj.cityName.append('abc')
onto.save(file="ntriplesFileName", format="ntriples")
```